# acmart titlenote does not work

Tags: footnotes, overleaf, acmart

\titlenote is not working. It always shows "Title note" in the generated pdf.

```
\documentclass[sigplan, anonymous]{acmart}

 \begin{document}
 \title{Title}
 \titlenote{This title note does not show!}

 \begin{abstract}
 This paper provides a sample of a \LaTeX\ document which conforms,
 somewhat loosely, to the formatting guidelines for
 ACM SIG Proceedings.
 \end{abstract}
 \maketitle

 \end{document}
```

[Here you have the link to the overleaf document](https://www.overleaf.com/16150905cdyvbqjsvwhq#/61747417/).

Comment: Create a new project from one of the ACM templates listed here: https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/acm These have the updated `acmart.cls` that does provide `\titlenote`.

Comment: You must [download the ACM template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) and include it into your project. If you detect some error in the template, you may [create a new issue in the corresponding Github project](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues).

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have enabled the `anonymous` option to the document class.

This is wanted, as the title note might contain details useful for the identification of the authors, so it is suppressed with the `anonymous` option.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! From my point of view this sound more a less like a comment.